# Django doesn't read from database – no error

Tags: python-2.7, osx-mavericks, postgresql-9.1, django-1.6

I just set up the environment for an existing Django project, on a new Mac. I know for certain there is nothing wrong with the code itself (just cloned the repo), but for some reason, Django can't seem to retrieve data from the database.

- I know the correct tables and data is in the db.
- I know the codebase is as it should be.
- I can make queries using the Django shell.
- Django doesn't throw any errors despite the data missing on the web page.

I realize that it's hard to debug this without further information, but I would really appreciate a finger pointing me to the right direction. I can't seem to find any useful logs.

**EDIT:**

I just realized the problem lies elsewhere. Unfortunately I can't delete this post with the bounty still open.

Comment: ah you posted your edit right as I posted my reply - what was the problem in the end?

Comment: Your answer was just what I was looking for, so I will reward it anyways. The problem, embarrassingly enough, was that the database was empty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing any code, I can only suggest some general advice that might help you debug your problem. Please add a link to your repository if you can or some snippets of your database settings, the view which includes the database queries etc...

**Debugging the view**

The first thing I would recommend is using the [python debugger](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) inside the `view` which queries the database. If you've not used `pdb` before, it's a life saver which allows you to set breakpoints in your Python script and then interactively execute code inside the interpreter

```
>>> import pdb
>>> pdb.set_trace()
>>> # look at the results of your queries
```

If you are using the Django ORM, the `QuerySet` returned from the query should have all the data you expect.

If it doesn't then you need to look into your database configuration in `settings.py`.

If it does, then you must might not be returning that object to the template? Unlikely as you said the code was the same, but double check the objects you pass with your [HttpResponse](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/panels.html#sql) object.

**Debugging the database settings**

If you can query the database using the project settings inside `settings.py` from the django shell it sounds unlikley that there is a problem with this - but like everything double check.

You said that you've set up a new project on a mac. What is on a different operating system before? Maybe there is a problem with the paths now - to make your project platform independent remember to use the [`os.path.join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) method when working with file paths.

And what about the username and password details....

**Debugging the template**

Maybe your template is referencing the wrong object variable name or object attribute.You mentioned that

> Django doesn't throw any errors despite the data missing on the web
>   page.

This doesn't really tell us much - to quote the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#variables) -

> If you use a variable that doesn’t exist, the template system will
>   insert the value of the TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID setting, which is
>   set to '' (the empty string) by default.

So to check all the variables available to your template, you could use the [debug](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#debug) template tag

```
{{ debug }}
```

Probably even better though is to use the [django-debugging-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) - this will also let you examine the SQL queries your `view` is making.

**Missing Modules**

I would expect this to raise an exception if this were the problem, but have you checked that you have the [psycopg](http://initd.org/psycopg/) module on your new machine?